# How to make flexbox not take up the entire viewport width?

Tags: css, flexbox

I tried searching and could not find an exact similar question, so posting it here.
So I have a few block divs inside a flex wrapper with row wrapping, and I want to have a border for the wrapper. The issue I'm running into is that the border will always span 100% of the viewport, instead of being reduced to fit only the items. How can  I achieve this without using media queries or JS? I would prefer solutions with inline styles as that's the most preferable in this scenario.

Code samples:
Basic code for my blocks:

```
<div id="w1" class=wrapper style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center; gap: 3px; border: 3px solid #000">  <!-- wrapper OPEN -->
    <div id="b1" class="block" style="width: 250px;"></div>
    .
    .
    .
    <div id="b9" class="block" style="width: 250px;"></div>
</div><!-- wrapper CLOSE -->
```

[image: Basic code]

So basically, this border should be here:[image]

I tried a solution to add another wrapper outside with `display:table` but it only works when all blocks are on the same row; when blocks wrap to the next row; it again takes up the entire width.

```
<div id="w0" class=outer style="display:table; margin:auto; border: 3px solid #000;"><!-- border wrapper OPEN -->
    <div id="w1" class=wrapper style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center; gap: 3px;"><!-- flex wrapper OPEN -->
        <div id="b1" class="block" style="width: 250px;"></div>
        .
        .
        .
        <div id="b9" class="block" style="width: 250px;"></div>
    </div><!-- flex wrapper CLOSE -->
</div><!-- border wrapper CLOSE -->
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue I'm running into is that the border will always span 100% of the viewport, instead of being reduced to fit only the items.

Instead of `display:flex;` use `display: inline-flex`.

```html
<div id="w1" class=wrapper style="display: inline-flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center; gap: 3px; border: 3px solid #000">  

<!-- wrapper OPEN -->
    <div id="b1" class="block" style="width: 250px;"></div>
 
    <!-- rest of your code -->
```

---

#### SideNote:

Your div is a block level element.

> A block-level element always takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can). [link](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_blocks.asp)

Block-level elements may contain other block-level elements or inline elements.

> An inline element does not start on a new line.
> An inline element only takes up as much width as necessary. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_blocks.asp)

Inline elements cannot contain block-level elements.

If you define `display: inline-flex;`, it turns your element into `inline-block` element and You will get the best of both world.

---

#### EDIT

> it takes up the entire width of the viewport when items have wrapped to the next row.

It is how `flexbox` is supposed to behave. Otherwise, you should use `grid` instead of `flexbox`.

> Problem with grid: The last div block would be aligned to one of the columns instead of being centered. Would there be a way to archive to center last div?

Yes possible.

If you can use external css file or internal css

assuming you want to columns, you can do something like this

```html
<div id="w1" class=wrapper style="display: inline-grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center; gap: 3px; border: 3px solid #000;" >
...
```

```css
.wrapper .block:last-child {
 justify-self: center;
 grid-column-start: span 2;
}
```

> I would prefer solutions with inline styles as that's the most preferable in this scenario.

If you have to use inline css then on the last `div.block` element, you should define above css styles inline.

```html
<div id="w1" class=wrapper style="display: inline-grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center; gap: 3px; border: 3px solid #000;" >  <!-- wrapper OPEN -->
    <div id="b1" class="block" style="width: 250px;"></div>
    .
    .
    .
    <div id="b9" class="block" style="width: 250px; justify-self: center;
 grid-column-start: span 2;"></div>
</div><!-- wrapper CLOSE -->
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea; however while `inline-flex` does make the wrapper take only the width of the item when all child divs are in the same row, it takes up the entire width of the viewport when items have wrapped to the next row, such as shown in the example image above.

Comment: @RugsB3 it is how flexbox is supposed to behave. Otherwise, either you should set a `max-width` on this wrapper element or use `grid` instead of `flexbox`

Comment: The examples where I've had to use Grid, the last div block would be aligned to one of the columns instead of being centered. (eg, the brown block in the above image goes under the orange block, instead of being centered under the orange and purple blocks) Would there be a way to archive the this?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve this without using media queries or JS? I would
> prefer solutions with inline styles as that's the most preferable in
> this scenario.

Depending on your need, the solution is to easily add a `width` for the flex wrapper and add the `gap` value to it. in your case, it should be `width: 503px` since each child has `width: 250px`.

Add `margin: 0 auto` for centering the wrapper.

```html
<div id="w1" class=wrapper style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center; gap: 3px; border: 3px solid #000;width: 503px;margin: 0 auto" >  <!-- wrapper OPEN -->
    <div id="b1" class="block" style="background-color: skyblue;width: 250px; height: 100px"></div>
    <div id="b1" class="block" style="background-color: skyblue;width: 250px; height: 100px"></div>
    <div id="b1" class="block" style="background-color: skyblue;width: 250px; height: 100px"></div>
    <div id="b1" class="block" style="background-color: skyblue;width: 250px; height: 100px"></div>
    <div id="b1" class="block" style="background-color: skyblue;width: 250px; height: 100px"></div>
    <div id="b1" class="block" style="background-color: skyblue;width: 250px; height: 100px"></div>
    <div id="b1" class="block" style="background-color: skyblue;width: 250px; height: 100px"></div>
    <div id="b1" class="block" style="background-color: skyblue;width: 250px; height: 100px"></div>
    <div id="b1" class="block" style="background-color: skyblue;width: 250px; height: 100px"></div>
</div><!-- wrapper CLOSE -->
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; however, I apologize for not clarifying, the layout shown in the image above is on a smaller viewport. On large enough viewports, all the divs would ideally be on the same row.